# getReadProof for specific event

Tags: storage, events

I want to generate a `StorageProof` for a specific event that is stored in storage. I have found `System_Events` but this returns me all events of a block, instead of a specific one. I stumbled on `getChildReadProof` and am thinking the `childStorageKey` could be the index in the `Vec<Event>` but am unable to generate valid calls, and have the suspicion this is incorrect in general.

Is there another module I'm missing for accessing events and performing a storage proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently not efficient way to proof only the existence of one event. So, you need to read all events in the moment.

However there is an issue open to improve the situation: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11216

Comment: understood, will track the issue. Thanks!